# Get multiple line paragraph to appear in line

Tags: html, css

I've never used HTML before, but have managed to put something together, but I am having trouble making a paragraph line up.

I am currently getting this:

**Owner**:  TextText Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text TextText TextTextTextText Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text TextText TextText Text Text Text Text TextText Text

[Image of current text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgxGB.png)

But i would like to set it up so it appears like this (Minus the line):

**Owner**: TextText Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text TextText TextTextTextText Text Text Text ________TextText Text Text Text Text

[wanted results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chwhp.png)

This is what i am using:

```css
.titlefield {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```
<div><span class="titlefield">Managers Hours: </span><span class="itemvalue">{{item.ManagersHours}}</span></div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused what you want. What needs to line up to what? Can you maybe post a screenshot of the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Include your HTML markup.

Comment: @mousetail i've updated the request to contain images of what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Put **Owner** and **TextTextText** into separate elements, and give them a parent that uses the style **display: flex**

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <h3>Owner</h3>
  <p>TextText Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text TextText TextTextTextText Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `align-items:baseline;` in style to align the title and the paragraphe correctly